# How to turn off "auto-correction" in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

When chatting in Microsoft Teams, the program will frequently auto-"correct" text that I type, or even more often, text that I paste. This frequently causes problems, as it changes the meaning of what I am saying. Even worse, it can cause URLs to break, or code snippets to be incorrect. One particularly egregious example was when I tried to paste a URL into the chat which included a query string. One parameter in the query string was like "...something&REGIONID=something", and Teams "corrected" "&REGIONID" to "®IONID". This caused the URL to not work, and the only way I could fix it was to manually edit the text after Teams broke it.
Is there any setting to turn these auto-corrections/auto-formatting off, so Teams just keeps whatever I type or paste and leaves it alone?

Answer (score 0):

Teams uses it's own spell checker, not the one from Word, etc.  I've read on other threads that to avoid things getting autocorrected, you should type your message into another app, then copy and paste.  Very lame, but that's the best I've found.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150938)

Answer (score -1):

Surely this is just the Spell check active:
See Settings --> General : Enable Spell Check option.

[image: Settings page in Teams]

Comment: One would think, but no. I've turned that off, but it only controls spell-checking. It doesn't control the auto-reformatting/auto-replacement that Teams does.
So now, I no longer get spelling suggestions, but if I paste a URL with "&REGIONID" in it, Teams still changes it to "®IONID". Also "*.txt, *.dat" still gets changed so the asterisks are removed and replaced with bolded text.

Comment: ok, ill leavr this here so other can see it isnt the answer.